# Can you add a folder structure to IIS7?

Tags: iis-7, windows-server-2008

I am in the process of setting up a new server which I share with 2 colleagues. Is it possible to get a folder structure into IIS7 at all (in the MMC) so we can keep our sites seperate?

In the IIS7 management console I would like a set of folders foreach of my colleagues so that each of our websites are within their own sub folder.

Comment: Please explain the scenario you'd like to achieve in more detail. I've got a feeling that what you want to achieve is not only possible, but also very simple - but try to be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

IIS used to ship with a set of scripts/programs that you could use to programmatically manage virtual directories (iisvdir).

Separating the code into virtual directories provides some measure of separation.